# How to edit a commit in Git?

Tags: git

I wanted to change a commit in Git for which I googled and found this command:

```
git commit --amend
```

When I pass this command, I get a screen which look something like this:

[image]

When I start typing commit here, it just plays sound similar to one that sort of means that I am typing in a wrong place (invalid command).

Can someone please help me in figuring out how we can edit a commit message in Git?

Comment: Your problem isn't with git, it's with vi. Either you learn vi or you configure git to use another editor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming but about how to type text in the vi editor

Comment: fast cheat sheet: Type `i` to enter some text, then `esc`, then `:x` and enter.

Comment: I like to use the ZZ shortcut to save and exit.

Comment: I think a simple answer should have been "what you are seeing is a vim terminal interface, as it shows on the bottom of your pasted screenshot" and then you can point him to vim documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To edit a commit message in Git:

First as you have mentioned give the command:

```
git commit --amend
```

Then it will popup  the screen you have given in your question.

Then press <kbd>i</kbd> which will make it possible to edit the commit message. Then move your cursor to the your previous commit message using arrow keys

> Created Intial Schema

And edit it.

Next press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key on your keyboard.

Next type the command press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> key on your keyboard

```
:
```

Then type `wq` after the colon. And press <kbd>Enter</kbd> save and exit.

```
:wq
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way to change the last commit do this is:

```
git commit -m "<new_message>" --amend
```